# How to display tabular data in PHP?

Tags: php, html, asp.net

I am coming from Asp.net world, where everything is so modular that it creates headaches and nausea sometimes and you forget what you were actually doing.

Here in PHP I was trying to study how to display tabular data, and the solution was very simple but that looked very hasty, because if I write lots of code then it will become haywire.

So my question is what standard should I follow to work with repeating data, if there is any? Please guide me to some quality material to study because I tried but did not find anything. I have [studied this link](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm).
**[Edit]**
The way asp.net render tabular data is by using [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). here you just create an instance of the `GridView` class and send it the data retrieved from the database and remain job is done behind the scene without messing the C# or VB code with html or writing the same logic again and again. I mean it is nice example of code resuability and I want to utilize something similar here in php to write the repeating code once and then inherit it if I want it somewhere else.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific since I can't really find a question here, for example, what do you mean by tabular data specifically? The scope of this may be too broad.

Comment: The question is abit confusing without code. Please add some code.

Comment: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm  checked this one but not sure if its ok.

Comment: From what you linked it seems to need to learn HTML, CSS, PHP (loops etc) and MySQL seperately.

Comment: @Ozmah yes I intended to study all the methods to display MySql data in different way. Like, in table form or Ol,Ul form etc.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I know about the spices of web programming  :) they are yummy :D

Comment: @user2638682 lol. Well the material in the link is horrible. It suffers from a deprecated use of mysql_* functions, SQL injection security holes, mixes html and php and alot of bad practice.

Comment: I mean I am trying to understand if I can work to modularize the code properly. and yes I have studied smarty a bit too, if this is coming in the suggestion. :)

Comment: It is very recommended to use modualarized code, but the link you supplied has nothing to do with it. Smarty is for templating also not about modules. Take a look at phptherightway (you are probably looking for something like composer), it has a nice guide to get to know php

Comment: @RonniSkansing my question was not about the link provided ... it was an example of what I was looking for.. I know it does not use the parameterized queries etc.. and one thing that you mentioned is that mixing php code with html and that is exactly what I am looking for, not to mix different things in hasty ways.. you killed my question Bro!! :(

Comment: @user2638682 =/ seems noone has been able to read that out of the question (including me). Please edit your question and try to make it more understandable. Maybe pull in a asp example of how you are used to working with things.

Comment: @RonniSkansing code edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself have migrated from ASP.NET to php and one word of advice is forget what ever you learnt in ASP.net as ASP.net abstracts a lot of thing in web development to a point you forget that you are working with basic html/jscript and http. but again, this is just a personal opinion.

Ragarding your question on how to display a table and populate it with data. Have a look at this example. Here

```
<?php
    $people = array(
        array('Tom', '16'),
        array('John', '21'),
        array('Kate', '19'),
        array('Luke', '25')
    )
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td><td>Age</td>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($people as $person){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $person[0]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $person[1];  ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. I create a 2d array contain data about `People` and their `age`. Due to simplicity sake, im using a hard coded array and not retrieving data from a database.
2. I then use a while loop to loop through the data in the array and for each tuple, I add a `<tr>` in the table. This is something like a `repeater` in ASP.NET

## [DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19a9a5700d1bccb05d251dd0abb70868365fc041)

---

### **Just noticed you want a modularized version. Here is an example:**

**index.php**

```
<?php
include('inc.datasource.php');

$people = DataSource::getUsers();

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td><td>Age</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Render rows with data -->
            <?php foreach($people as $person){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $person[0]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $person[1];  ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <!-- End render rows with data -->

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**inc.database.php**

```
<?php
class DataSource{

    public static function getUsers(){
        //Connect to database
        //Retrieve user data
        //Return user data

        //Simulating the above steps for simplicity sake
        $people = array(
            array('Tom', '16'),
            array('John', '21'),
            array('Kate', '19'),
            array('Luke', '25')
        );
        return $people;
    }
}
?>
```

---

**If you want to completly seperate your php from your html. I suggest you use one of the php mvc frameworks. I personally like using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)**

Comment: aside from what the question of mine is(above), what is your opinion of both the languages? which one is better? So far I have liked php in the way it gives you control over the whole page rendering and above all no messy ViewStates(hhhh). I always laugh at the Microsoft over the design of asp.net. I want to meet its designers and pinch them till I pour out all my exhaustion.. :D

Comment: @user2638682 TBH I hate asp.net. I wish I had learnt webDev starting with php. I started of with ASP.NET when I was 16 and for 3 years I stuck to it until I decided to try out php. I was shocked to learn that I didnt know ANYthing about webdev. I didn't even know what a get/post request was which is the fundamental thing http is built upon... So in short. PHP is always my #1 choice as it let you control everything on your page. No messy abstractions by ASP.NET and retarded objects that you drag and drop in visual studio lol.

Comment: Ok that is nice @krimson Thanks.

Comment: If you found the answer useful and according to what you asked, you should accept it @user2638682